# Create an app on iPhone to get phone's gyrometer

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, app-store, dtmf

So here's the situation. Looking at the attached picture,[Block diagram of a cell phone controlled robotic vehicle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4VgT.jpg), I was wondering how to create an app on iPhone that would get the phone's gyrometer that connects to the DTMF decoder on the picture and connects to another iPhone (the remote) via Bluetooth so it can proceed forward to the microcontroller and so on. If anyone has link on steps to how to create an app, please tell me.

Other than that, if I dont use the option to create an app, I have alternative of using a decoder IC, but I dont know which mobile phones are compatible with this IC. I have an old iPhone 4S, nokia 7320, Samsung E1270 flip phone, and a samsung wave gt-s8500 handsets.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have access to the iPhone's gyroscope and accelerometer. Core Motion is probably the best way to do that.

As far as communicating the info to a robotic car, I'm not sure how DTMF fits in. It seems to me BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy) would be a much better way to go. There is a Core Bluetooth framework that lets you make an iPhone serve as either a peripheral or a central device.

I don't know how you'd do DTMF, but BLE seems a much better fit.